# i am having error that shows Error inflating class fragment by android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file

Tags: java, android, xml, kotlin, fragment

whenever my home activity opens in emulator this error shows-

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity 
ComponentInfo{com.example.adsho/com.example.adsho.HomeActivity}: 
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16 in 
com.example.adsho:layout/activity_home: Binary XML file line #22 in 
com.example.adsho:layout/content_home: Error inflating class fragment
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3622)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3786)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2257)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:233)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8030)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:631)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:978)
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16 in 
com.example.adsho:layout/activity_home: Binary XML file line #22 in 
com.example.adsho:layout/content_home: Error inflating class fragment
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #22 in 
com.example.adsho:layout/content_home: Error inflating class fragment
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.example.adsho.ui.home.HomeFragment.onCreateView(HomeFragment.kt:58)
    at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2963)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:518)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:282)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStore.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStore.java:112)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1647)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:3128)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchViewCreated(FragmentManager.java:3065)
    at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performViewCreated(Fragment.java:2988)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.ensureInflatedView(FragmentStateManager.java:392)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:281)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentLayoutInflaterFactory.onCreateView(FragmentLayoutInflaterFactory.java:140)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.onCreateView(FragmentController.java:135)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.dispatchFragmentsOnCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:319)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:298)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.tryCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:1070)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:995)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:959)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1131)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1092)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:1271)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1127)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1092)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:1271)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1127)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1092)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:680)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:532)
    at com.example.adsho.databinding.ActivityHomeBinding.inflate(ActivityHomeBinding.java:53)
2021-12-22 15:46:05.267 30467-30467/com.example.adsho E/AndroidRuntime:     at 
com.example.adsho.databinding.ActivityHomeBinding.inflate(ActivityHomeBinding.java:47)
    at com.example.adsho.HomeActivity.onCreate(HomeActivity.kt:37)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8006)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7990)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1329)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3595)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3786)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2257)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:233)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8030)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:631)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:978)
```

My activity_home xml file is-

```
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:openDrawer="start">

<include
    android:id="@+id/app_bar_home"
    layout="@layout/app_bar_home"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_home"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />
</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

here app_bar_home xml is-

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".HomeActivity">

<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.Adsho.AppBarOverlay">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/Theme.Adsho.PopupOverlay" />

</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

<include android:id="@+id/content_home"
    layout="@layout/content_home" />
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

and content_home xml is-

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_home">

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment_content_home"
    android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:visibility="visible"
    app:defaultNavHost="true"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I copied these xml files from my other project where they are working fine but here it is showing error, I tried different methods but error doesn't go. Thank you in advance.

HomeActivity file -

```
import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.Menu
import android.view.MenuItem
import android.view.View
import android.widget.TextView
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog
import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
import androidx.navigation.findNavController
import androidx.navigation.ui.AppBarConfiguration
import androidx.navigation.ui.navigateUp
import androidx.navigation.ui.setupActionBarWithNavController
import androidx.navigation.ui.setupWithNavController
import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat
import androidx.core.view.GravityCompat
import com.example.adsho.Model.UserInfoModel
import com.example.adsho.databinding.ActivityHomeBinding
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth
import com.google.firebase.database.*

class HomeActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

private lateinit var appBarConfiguration: AppBarConfiguration
private lateinit var binding: ActivityHomeBinding
private lateinit var auth: FirebaseAuth
private lateinit var database: FirebaseDatabase
private lateinit var userInfoRef: DatabaseReference

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    binding = ActivityHomeBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home)

    auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
    database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
    userInfoRef = database.reference.child("Users")
    val currentUser = auth.currentUser

    val toolbar = binding.appBarHome.toolbar
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar)

    val drawerLayout: DrawerLayout = binding.drawerLayout
    val navView: NavigationView = binding.navView
    val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment_content_home)
    // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
    // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
    appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(navController.graph, drawerLayout)
    setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
    navView.setupWithNavController(navController)
    navView.bringToFront()

    navView.menu.findItem(R.id.nav_sign_out).setOnMenuItemClickListener{
        signOutDialog()
        it.isCheckable = false
        true
    }

    navView.menu.findItem(R.id.nav_sign_in).setOnMenuItemClickListener {
        startActivity(Intent(this@HomeActivity, SignInActivity::class.java))
        it.isCheckable = false
        true
    }
}

override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.home, menu)
    return true
}

override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
    val id: Int = item.itemId

    if (id == R.id.action_notification_icon){
        invalidateOptionsMenu()
        findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment_content_home).navigate(R.id.action_notification_icon)
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
}

override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
    val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment_content_home)
    return navController.navigateUp(appBarConfiguration) || super.onSupportNavigateUp()
}

// on pressing back button navigation drawer will dismiss
override fun onBackPressed() {
    if (binding.drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        binding.drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START)
    }
    else {
        super.onBackPressed()
    }
}

// Sign out menu item will be shown only when user is signed in
override fun onStart() {
    super.onStart()
    val currentUser = auth.currentUser
    val signOutItem: MenuItem = binding.navView.menu.findItem(R.id.nav_sign_out)
    val signInItem: MenuItem = binding.navView.menu.findItem(R.id.nav_sign_in)
    val profileItem: MenuItem = binding.navView.menu.findItem(R.id.nav_profile)
    val navHeaderView: View = binding.navView.getHeaderView(0)
    val navHeaderUsername: TextView = navHeaderView.findViewById(R.id.nav_header_username)


    userInfoRef.child(currentUser!!.uid)
        .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object: ValueEventListener {
            override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                if (snapshot.exists()) {
                    val model = snapshot.getValue(UserInfoModel::class.java)
                    DBqueries.userDetailsInfo = model

                    val name: String = model!!.fullName.toString()
                    if (name.equals("anon")) {
                        navHeaderUsername.text = "Hello, anon"
                        signInItem.isVisible = true
                        signOutItem.isVisible = false
                        profileItem.isVisible = false
                    } else {
                        signOutItem.isVisible
                        signInItem.isVisible = false
                        profileItem.isVisible = true
                        navHeaderUsername.text = "Hello, $name"
                    }
                }
            }

            override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
                Toast.makeText(this@HomeActivity, error.message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show()
            }

        })
}

private fun signOutDialog() {
    val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(this@HomeActivity)
    builder.setTitle("Sign out")
        .setMessage("Do you really want to sign out?")
        .setNegativeButton("Cancel") {dialogInterface, _-> dialogInterface.dismiss()}
        .setPositiveButton("SIGN OUT") {dialogInterface, _->
            FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut()
            val intent = Intent(this@HomeActivity, SignInActivity::class.java)
            intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK
            startActivity(intent)
            finish()
        }.setCancelable(false)

    val dialog = builder.create()
    dialog.setOnShowListener {
        dialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE)
            .setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this@HomeActivity, android.R.color.holo_red_dark))
        dialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE)
            .setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this@HomeActivity, R.color.black))
    }
    dialog.show()
}
```

}

and home fragment file -

```
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.ImageView
import android.widget.ProgressBar
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.lifecycle.Observer
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.bumptech.glide.Glide
import com.example.adsho.Adapter.HomeAdapter
import com.example.adsho.DBqueries
import com.example.adsho.DBqueries.lists
import com.example.adsho.DBqueries.loadCategoriesName
import com.example.adsho.DBqueries.loadHomePage
import com.example.adsho.Model.HomeModel
import com.example.adsho.R
import com.example.adsho.databinding.FragmentHomeBinding

class HomeFragment : Fragment() {

private lateinit var homeRecyclerView: RecyclerView
private lateinit var homeRecyclerViewAdapter: HomeAdapter
private lateinit var progressBar: ProgressBar

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    val root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false)

    // jo bhi load hoga DBqueries se hoga taki speed badh sake

    progressBar = root.findViewById(R.id.home_frag_progressBar)
    val recyView: RecyclerView = root.findViewById(R.id.home_page_recyclerview)


    // Home Recycler View
    homeRecyclerView = root.findViewById(R.id.home_page_recyclerview)
    val homeLayoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(requireContext())
    homeLayoutManager.orientation = LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL
    homeRecyclerView.layoutManager = homeLayoutManager


    // We are checking whether the list is empty or not
    // If its empty then we'll refresh the adapter
    if (lists.size == 0) {
        loadCategoriesName.add("HOME")
        lists.add(ArrayList<HomeModel>())
        homeRecyclerViewAdapter = HomeAdapter(lists[0])

        val nome: String = DBqueries.userDetailsInfo!!.fullName
        loadHomePage(homeRecyclerViewAdapter, root.context, 0, nome)


        progressBar.visibility = View.GONE
        recyView.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    } else {
        homeRecyclerViewAdapter = HomeAdapter(lists[0])
        homeRecyclerViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()

        progressBar.visibility = View.GONE
        recyView.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    }
    homeRecyclerView.adapter = homeRecyclerViewAdapter

    // Home Recycler View

    return root
}
```

}

Comment: Can you please post your `HomeActivity` & `HomeFragment`  java/kotlin files?

Comment: Please include the package line from the posted source files.  It could be relevant.

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't you be using `DatabindingUtil.setContentView(R.layout.activity_home)` instead of `setContentView(activity, R.layout.activity_home)`.

If i am not wrong there is not need to call `binding = ActivityHomeBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)` you could simply

```
binding = DatabindingUtil.setContentView(R.layout.activity_home)
```

Answer (score 1):

I was facing similar issue and it is causing due to fragment tag. Here is the code that works for me
change from

```
<fragment
android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment_content_home"
android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
...
app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation" />
```

to this

```
<androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment_content_home"
android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
....
app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation" />
```